# Spring. THYMELEAF. Problems with resolving String by THYMELEAF

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf can't display and resolve my objects. I think, i do something wrong right in html file. pls check it

```
public class Ingredient {

    private final String id; 
    private final String name;
    private final Type type;

public static enum Type {
    WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
}
```

Taco class

```
public class Taco {


    private String name;
    private List<String> ingredients;

}
```

Controller  class

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
public class DesignTacoController {


@ModelAttribute
public void addIngredientsToModel(Model model) {
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
            new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
            new Ingredient("COTO", "Corn Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
            new Ingredient("GRBF", "Ground Beef", Type.PROTEIN),
            new Ingredient("CARN", "Carnitas", Type.PROTEIN),
            new Ingredient("TMTO", "Diced Tomatoes", Type.VEGGIES),
            new Ingredient("LETC", "Lettuce", Type.VEGGIES),
            new Ingredient("CHED", "Cheddar", Type.CHEESE),
            new Ingredient("JACK", "Monterrey Jack", Type.CHEESE),
            new Ingredient("SLSA", "Salsa", Type.SAUCE),
            new Ingredient("SRCR", "Sour Cream", Type.SAUCE)
    );

    Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
    for (Type type : types) {
        model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),
                filterByType(ingredients, type));
    }
}


@GetMapping
public String showDesignForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("design", new Taco());
    return "design";
}

@PostMapping
public String processDesign(@Valid @ModelAttribute("design") Taco design, Errors errors, Model model) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return "design";
    }


    log.info("Processing design: " + design);

    return "redirect:/orders/current";
}


private List<Ingredient> filterByType(
        List<Ingredient> ingredients, Type type) {
    return ingredients
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(type))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}}
```

HTML. Just part of it, i think problem is just in it. It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

```
<form method="POST" th:object="${design}">

<div class="ingredient-group" id="proteins">
            <h3>Pick your protein:</h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${protein}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}" />
                <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sorry for bad post, its first time, so..

Comment: Host cant display objects that i give by controller to html page. I think, i wrote smth wrong in html

Comment: Which Model attribute can't you see?

Comment: idea can't resolve "protein", "ingredient.id" and "ingredient.name" in this little html, that i ve given

Comment: See my answer. I think you misunderstood how to use the ModelAttribute method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaDoc for `@ModelAttribute` says

> Annotation that binds a method parameter or **method return value** to a
>   named model attribute

Your method doesn't return a value, as it's void.
Remove the annotation from `addIngredientsToModel` and call it inside your `showDesignForm` `@GetMapping` method.

```
@GetMapping
public String showDesignForm(Model model) {
    addIngredientsToModel(model);
    model.addAttribute("design", new Taco());
    return "design";
}
```

Alternatively, if you still want to have common attributes exposed via a `@ModelAttributes` method, you need to return a `Map<String, List<Ingredient>>` from that method.

```
@ModelAttribute("types")
public Map<String, List<Ingredient>> addIngredientsToModel() { ... }
```

Then you'll be able to access `protein` via

```
<div th:each="ingredient : ${types.get('protein')}">
   <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}" />
   <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
</div>
```